# generate pdf from tex from user without homedir

Tags: python, tomcat, latex, cgi

im trying to run pdflatex from a tomcat through a python cgi script.
but i get the error.

```
ERROR: Permission denied: readWrite="true", path="/home/user_from_which_i_switched_to_tomcat_user/.miktex/texmfs/data/miktex/data/le/d26685eb8f310815af8ade7524bcc869.fndb"
ERROR: Info: readWrite="true", path="/home/user_from_which_i_switched_to_tomcat_user/.miktex/texmfs/data/miktex/data/le/d26685eb8f310815af8ade7524bcc869.fndb"
ERROR: Source: Libraries/MiKTeX/Core/MemoryMappedFile/unx/unxMemoryMappedFile.cpp
ERROR: Line: 88
```

when i try to run the script as the tomcat user from the commandline.
Do i really need a home directory for the tomcat user to run pdflatex?
Or can i use another program that works without having an home dir to generate 
a pdf from tex.